# Splitting dataframe of duplicates based on criteria

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have a dataframe of duplicated Email Addresses.

| ID | EmailAddress | Name | Country | Distance | IDLen | NonNAN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 39203920 | john@gmail.com | John | UK | 12 | 8 | 6 |
| 32323 | john@gmail.com | NaN | UK | 12 | 5 | 5 |

I have created two additional columns that calculate the length of the ID and how many non NaN fields are for each row. I would like to create 2 new dataframes:

1. df1. Where the duplicate row has either the higher `NonNAN` value; or if they're the same, pick the lowest `IDLen`.
2. df2. The remaining rows

I was thinking of using the `df.duplicated()` function but it only looks at first or last and I need something more sophisticated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) What if there are more than 2 duplicate emails? How to split them between the 2 dataframes then? 2) If both `IDLen` and `NonNAN` are the same, then just pick at random?

Comment: 1. Whether there are 2 or more duplicates, follow the above rules. 2. pick the first or random. whichever is easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a boolean mask of rows you want to select for `df1` - then automatically the inverse of this mask will select the rows for `df2`.

---

For each group where `EmailAddress` is the same:

- `mask` selects all the rows where `NonNAN` has a maximum value.
- if `mask` selects multiple values -

  it must **also** select the rows where `IDLen` is the minimum.
- if `mask` still selects multiple values -

  just take the first one.

```py
def f(df):
    mask = df['NonNAN'] == df['NonNAN'].max()
    if mask.sum() > 1:
        mask = mask & (df['IDLen'] == df.loc[mask, 'IDLen'].min())
        if mask.sum() > 1:
            mask.iloc[mask.argmax()+1 : ] = False
    return mask

mask = df.groupby('EmailAddress', group_keys=False).apply(f)
mask = mask.reindex(df.index)

df1 = df[mask]
df2 = df[~mask]
```

Answer (score 2):

Will this work for you? The key is to sort the data, then apply `df.duplicated()`, which has very high efficiency rather than looping through each record like `.apply(lambda)` functions

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': [39203920, 32323, 22222, 392999], 
    'EmailAddress': ['john@gmail.com', 'j@email.com', 'j@email.com', 'john@gmail.com'], 
    'Name': ['John', np.nan, 'Jane', 'John'], 
    'Country': ['UK', 'UK', 'UK', 'UK'], 
    'Distance': [12, 12, 12, 12], 
    'IDLen': [8, 5, 5, 6], 
    'NonNAN': [6, 5, 6, 6] })
df = df.sort_values(['EmailAddress', 'NonNAN', 'IDLen'], ascending=[True, False, True])

         ID    EmailAddress  Name Country  Distance  IDLen  NonNAN
2     22222     j@email.com  Jane      UK        12      5       6
1     32323     j@email.com   NaN      UK        12      5       5
3    392999  john@gmail.com  John      UK        12      6       6
0  39203920  john@gmail.com  John      UK        12      8       6
```

Based on your rules, I have sorted the data so that the desired record is located first. When `df.duplicated()` is applied on `EmailAddress`, the first record will be kept

```
df1 = df[~df.duplicated('EmailAddress')]
       ID    EmailAddress  Name Country  Distance  IDLen  NonNAN
2   22222     j@email.com  Jane      UK        12      5       6
3  392999  john@gmail.com  John      UK        12      6       6

df2 = df[df.duplicated('EmailAddress')]
         ID    EmailAddress  Name Country  Distance  IDLen  NonNAN
1     32323     j@email.com   NaN      UK        12      5       5
0  39203920  john@gmail.com  John      UK        12      8       6
```

If your `ID` column is numerical (ie, not alphanumeric), you can sort based on ascending `ID`, and there is no need for the column `IDLen` (because you would like the shortest one if 'NonNAN' is the same)

Answer (score 2):

You can absolutely use `duplicated`, you just have to sort your data according to your conditions.

Given `df`:

```
         ID    EmailAddress    Name Country  Distance  IDLen  NonNAN
0  39203920  john@gmail.com    John      UK        12      8       6
1     32323  john@gmail.com     NaN      UK        12      5       5
2      2423   bob@gmail.com     Bob     AUS        32      2       4
3     24233   bob@gmail.com  Robert     AUS        32      2       5
```

Doing:

```
df = df.sort_values(['NonNAN', 'ID'], ascending=[False, True])
mask = df.duplicated('EmailAddress')
df1 = df[~mask]
df2 = df[mask]
print(df1)
print(df2)

# Output df1:

         ID    EmailAddress    Name Country  Distance  IDLen  NonNAN
0  39203920  john@gmail.com    John      UK        12      8       6
3     24233   bob@gmail.com  Robert     AUS        32      2       5

# Output df2:

      ID    EmailAddress Name Country  Distance  IDLen  NonNAN
1  32323  john@gmail.com  NaN      UK        12      5       5
2   2423   bob@gmail.com  Bob     AUS        32      2       4
```